# Android: Intent- FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I have three activities say A B C , from activity A i go to B and and search  city and from Activity B iam going to Activity c , in c iam saving something which i put in Async task
 and this will be saved in Activit A listview, the problem is after saving in the list when i hit back button i again see the Activity A  with not saving the name which i previously saved

```
private class Savecity extends AsyncTask<city, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(result != null && result.equals("sucess")){

            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, cityActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            startActivity(intent);}

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(city... arg0) {
            try {
                ((CityPreferences) activity.getApplication()).createcity(arg0[0]);

                return "sucess";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "", e);
                return "fail";
            }
        }
```

Comment: your question title and inner-description doesn't relate. Anyhow, you  need to refresh the list in activity A once you save your data

Comment: i can see the data in activity A and when i click the back button i again see the activity A with no saved data..

Comment: Hi, are you testing this on Android 7? Or you're getting the same behavior in any OS version? I'm facing this problem but on Android 7 only.

Comment: Word of warning, if the activity you're launching launches others, using no-history control will cause the current activity to automatically finish immediately after launch.

Comment: any solution?..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually in your activity `C` when you are trying to re-call activity `A`, all you need to do is to clear **activity-stack**. For example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity_A.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: hi sorry actually itz working with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP),  thank you

Answer (score 21):

You can implement this from your AndroidManifest.xml file, just add `android:noHistory="true"` attribute in those `<activity>` you want

hope this helps..

Comment: @Zennon..hey actually itz working, previously i have put it wrong activity..thanks a lot

Comment: some issues when click the back button without going to activity C, it is loosing its history which should not happen, it should only loose history when comming from Activity C

Comment: hi it worked with Waqas answer and   android:noHistory="true" solve my other issue thank you